# Is there a way to communicate with a driver from a C application?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel, driver

The kernel communicates with drivers that means my application could do it as well maybe doing system calls? For example I would like to simulate a click in my application is there a way I can send some input to the mouse driver and achieve this or make a system call to achieve the simulation? Bottom line, I would like to know if it's possible to talk to drivers using C and how would I go about doing this?

Comment: Be more specific in your tagging, linux-kernel tag perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, check the `/dev/<device>` entry in your file system that the driver has created and access the `/dev/<device>` as a file from your user application and perform `open`/`read`/`write`/`close` operations on it. The corresponding `read`/`write` in the driver will be called. If you need to define specific functions then you need to define [`ioctls`](http://linux.die.net/lkmpg/x892.html) in your driver code.

Comment: when working with serial ports, the ioctls part can be a little tricky, especially when dealing with hardware flow control where you are required to raise and lower pins, timing is critical.